# Android patttern lock reset

Tags: adb, broken-screen, locked-out, pattern-lock, sony-xperia-z1

Awesome people! I need help!

My wife's old Xperia z1 has a broken digitizer, the phone is pattern locked without showing the path. Of course, no one can remember the pattern, USB debugging is not enabled, no root and no google account shows that it is paired with this device. I care about photos so is there any way to take a memory dump to an SD card or to clone the phone content without debugging mode? If I wipe the data in the boot menu, will I be able to recover the photos using e.g. Recuve? Can I run some script from SD card without permissions in the system? Or any other way to bypass pattern lock without debugging and root?

Comment: So not only the touchscreen is dead, but also you've forgotten the pattern, and the phone is also not rooted?

Comment: The Xperia z1 is a very old phone shipped with Android 4.2. This phone should not be encrypted (unless you activated it manually) hence file recovery should be possible.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! May I recommend taking a look at the data recovery section in our [broken-screen tag wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info)? Also consider the linked and related questions from relevant Q&As. Another good starting point is our [locked-out tag wiki](/tags/locked-out/info). It's core Q&A, [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](/q/35847/16575), has a large collection of ways to reset the pattern.

Comment: hold vol down + power to enter fastboot mode, connect phone to pc, install platform-tools, post the output of fastboot getvar all (edit your question) then let's see whats next